# Changing a svg image id path color dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I used JS to put a SVG on the screen the code looks like this;

```
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};

imageObj.src = mysvg.svg;
```

But now I would like to change its color. But only the stroke1 id path

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="stroke1" d="M104.172,243.778c-19.76,28.41-32.721,45.681-38.883,51.843l-25.922-33.328c46.896-56.761,77.766-127.757,92.578-212.929
    l37.031,12.961c7.405,3.703,6.77,6.799-1.853,9.258c-6.19,34.572-16.058,67.293-29.625,98.133L104.172,243.778z"/>
<path d="M241.188,156.754c-16.058,32.113-33.328,58.643-51.845,79.617l-27.772-24.07c33.328-35.787,58.006-88.238,74.063-157.383
    l35.18,3.703c12.324,2.488,11.718,6.799-1.852,12.961l-14.813,49.993L241.188,156.754z"/>
<path d="M256,249.333c11.109,3.703,10.473,8.042-1.852,12.96c-11.109,62.953-26.56,111.73-46.289,146.273l-33.328-16.664
    c20.975-35.787,36.395-85.779,46.289-149.977L256,249.333z"/>
<path d="M405.977,238.223c27.138,56.791,46.289,104.931,57.398,144.421l-40.734,12.961c-9.895-40.734-26.559-89.482-49.991-146.273
    L405.977,238.223z"/>
<path d="M103.172,468.816V243.563l33.758-75.02l8.485,2.122l0.196,0.196c1.779,1.779,2.565,3.631,2.335,5.503
    c-0.293,2.384-2.173,4.635-5.744,6.872v285.58H103.172z"/>
<polygon points="382.413,218.462 408.168,157.754 239.753,157.754 253.451,120.575 418.319,120.575 424.109,108.995 
    466.786,138.093 456.82,148.059 423.218,232.064 "/>
<path d="M335.616,156.754V436.34c0,19.73-8.65,29.625-25.922,29.625h-49.992l-11.108-38.883h42.586c4.918,0,7.405-2.459,7.405-7.406
    V156.754H335.616z"/>
</svg>
```

What can I do to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the SVG inline and then manipulate it, e.g. (try on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEte2/)):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var changeColor = function() {
        document.getElementById("stroke1").setAttribute("style","fill:red")
      };
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="changeColor()">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
      <path id="stroke1" d="M104.172,243.778c-19.76,28.41-32.721,45.681-38.883,51.843l-25.922-33.328c46.896-56.761,77.766-127.757,92.578-212.929     l37.031,12.961c7.405,3.703,6.77,6.799-1.853,9.258c-6.19,34.572-16.058,67.293-29.625,98.133L104.172,243.778z"/>
      <path d="M241.188,156.754c-16.058,32.113-33.328,58.643-51.845,79.617l-27.772-24.07c33.328-35.787,58.006-88.238,74.063-157.383     l35.18,3.703c12.324,2.488,11.718,6.799-1.852,12.961l-14.813,49.993L241.188,156.754z"/>
      <path d="M256,249.333c11.109,3.703,10.473,8.042-1.852,12.96c-11.109,62.953-26.56,111.73-46.289,146.273l-33.328-16.664     c20.975-35.787,36.395-85.779,46.289-149.977L256,249.333z"/>
      <path d="M405.977,238.223c27.138,56.791,46.289,104.931,57.398,144.421l-40.734,12.961c-9.895-40.734-26.559-89.482-49.991-146.273     L405.977,238.223z"/>
      <path d="M103.172,468.816V243.563l33.758-75.02l8.485,2.122l0.196,0.196c1.779,1.779,2.565,3.631,2.335,5.503     c-0.293,2.384-2.173,4.635-5.744,6.872v285.58H103.172z"/>
      <polygon points="382.413,218.462 408.168,157.754 239.753,157.754 253.451,120.575 418.319,120.575 424.109,108.995      466.786,138.093 456.82,148.059 423.218,232.064 "/>
      <path d="M335.616,156.754V436.34c0,19.73-8.65,29.625-25.922,29.625h-49.992l-11.108-38.883h42.586c4.918,0,7.405-2.459,7.405-7.406     V156.754H335.616z"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: To fetch the SVG and make it inline, I'd maybe use something like this:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.overrideMimeType("image/svg+xml");
request.open("GET",filename,false);
request.send("");
document.body.appendChild(document.adoptNode(request.responseXML.documentElement));
```

(This is untested and in this form probably too sloppy for serious code. But it should make clear the idea.)

Comment: The problem is that i cant just write the svg on the html... i am going to get around 500 svg one bigger than other... and it came dynamically by using "imageObj.src = VARIABLE" ...

Comment: Is it an option to load the images using Ajax instead of the Image object? Then you could throw them in as inline SVG. The data has to be loaded and handled by the browser one way or the other. I'll include this in my suggestion.

Comment: You need to import the nodes into the document before you can append them, otherwise you can get a security exception. `document.body.appendChild(document.adoptNode(request.responseXML.documentElement));` or `document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(request.responseXML.documentElement));` (the former is preferred).

Comment: the code you @ThomasW just wrote i couldn't understand how to draw the image on the canvas, but anyway i guess that will bring me an svg treated as an image.. i am using an js which allows me to draw (http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) on the screen, basically i am detecting where was the first click and which point it was release last so i can know by the mouse tracking coordinates if it was nearly to the right A to B point i said it should be... so if that was correct (Nearly or exactly) it could paint the path id of the svg with some color...

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tool? I guess you might be better off using pure SVG instead of a canvas/SVG mix (depends on what you're doing). If you're up to something like this:
  http://jsfiddle.net/JeaN4/
then drop canvas. SVG offers stuff like tooltips, CSS highlighting and mouse event handling out of the box.

Comment: what i want to do is not just highlight each stroke on mouse over, i would like to draw over the svg and if i stroke it right by saying when mouse down (get coordinates XY) when mouse up (Get XY again) then compare the first XY is between (300,200)(for example) ? so it is right then test mouse up if both is right then fill the correspondent stroke red...

Comment: Ah, I see. Are there only straight lines involved, or also curved ones? I.e., do you only have to consider start and end point or also everything in between?